# What is the most efficient and easy way to cat/grep and cut to an output file in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, file, unix, grep

I want to do the following in Ruby:

```
cat </dirpath/file.*> | grep <pattern> | grep <pattern2> | cut <options> > <path>/output.txt
```

Comment: The easiest way? `system("cat </dirpath/file.*> | grep <pattern> | grep <pattern2> | cut <options> > <path>/output.txt")`

Comment: `system` is a Ruby command.

Comment: One-liner, and you've got it mostly written already. I honestly can't think of a way in Ruby that would be easier.

Comment: It's important to not discount using the built-in commands. They're highly optimized and battle-hardened, and, as a result are very fast and robust. Replacing them with pure Ruby is often a lot slower, so run some benchmarks and see.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir.grep("/dirpath/file.*")
.map{|f| File.read(f)}
.join($/)
.grep(pattern)
.grep(pattern2)
.slice(options)
.tap{|s| File.write("path/output.txt", s)}
```